# Execution of same code taking longer in IIS than in desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, performance, iis

I have a module that performs multiple SQL Server database operations.

When I execute this module in IIS (inside RESTful Service), the execution of this module takes about twice the time it takes while executing inside desktop application in the same computer.

In both, IIS and Desktop applications, software factors such as number of database operations, data impacted, etc are same.

I tried changing various properties in application pool, but I could not lower the running time in IIS to match to that in desktop application.

Are there any settings in IIS which help lowering the running time of the module?

Is running in IIS is supposed to be slower than in normal desktop application? Why?

Comment: The IIS is extremely Multitasking like most Webservers. That means it is under much bigger Memory Pressure. And memory pressure in a GC managed runtime can easily account for any increase in Runtime. Of course first we have to see if you are even measuring the proper way. In the JiT Compiled, Garbage Collected world of .NET getting high value Performance mesurements is far from trivial. Even just how you measure the passed time can throw massive amounts of measurement uncertainty into the equation.

Comment: are you measuring just the time your code takes to run or how long the restful service takes to return?

Comment: While you have the time to try many settings, spare some to really run a profiler against your web application so as to understand how the time is consumed. Only that can tell the real culprit and then you can solve it.

Comment: @zaitsman I measured the time taken to execute the code by using C# Stopwatch class. Total time taken by RESTful service is slightly more than the time taken by the code.